# Clean up KVM / libvirt

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I installed the "Virtual machine host" feature during installation of my 16.04 server. I'll run VMs exclusively on my local network so I don't need virbr0, dnsmasq and iptables rules, just to mention the things which annoy me so far.

Is there a way to clean up KVM / libvirt without breaking anything? Would it help if I reinstalled and used apt instead of tasksel?